# Generic Windows Account To Query Data

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, connection-string

I have been able to run the following VBA code (within Excel) using my own Windows account to pull data from a SQL server:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = ServerName;Trusted_connection=yes;"
```

However, now I'm at the point where I have additional users I would like to provide the file so that they can run the VBA and refresh the data (among other things).  I have a generic Windows account that I would like to use, however the solution is not as simple as changing the connection string as shown below because the password is not a SQL server password but rather a Windows password.

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = ServerName;UID=user;PWD=password"
```

I've read about things such as "impersonation", but haven't been able to figure it out.  Is there any reasonably simple solution to make this work?  Much thanks!

Comment: The problem with the latter option is that the password and username are stored, as raw text, in the Macro. Why don't you, instead, configure an AD group Login and User on your SQL Serve; with permissions to run the sp you use. Then have the user's that need to use the macro added to that AD Group.

Comment: Why are you using a generic Windows account instead of a generic SQL Server account? That would make your code work.

Comment: @SunKnight0 A "generic SQL Server Account"? Are you talking about a SQL Login? Trusted Connected are more secure; if you can use them, you should (the OP has made the right choice).